# Typescript raises error trying to return string array OR undefined from function

Tags: arrays, typescript, function

I have a shallow differences function that takes two string arrays as an arguments and returns either **undefined** (if arguments are of the different length) or **string array** of matching characters in these two string arrays. If the characters don't match, it will place undefined in the resulting array. So, I typed function return type as string[] | undefined.

```
export function shallowDifferences(
  a: string[],
  b: string[]
): string[] | undefined {
  if (a.length !== b.length) return undefined;

  let diff = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === b[i]) {
      diff[i] = a[i];
    } else {
      diff[i] = undefined;
    }
  }

  return diff;
}
```

Now TypeScript gives me an error:

Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

How to define return type for such a function correctly?

Comment: Why are you setting `diff[i]` to undefined? Shouldn't the return type be `(string | undefined)[] | undefined` then? You're returning an array that contains strings or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the error message closely, you can see what is wrong. It says `(string | undefined)[]` is not assignable to type `string[]`. That's your variable `diff` where it can be:

```
1) diff is string[]
a = ['a', 'b']
b = ['a', 'b']
diff = ['a', 'b']

2) diff is undefined[]
a = ['a', 'b']
b = ['c', 'd']
diff = [undefined, undefined]

3) diff is (string | undefined)[]
a = ['a', 'b']
b = ['a', 'c']
diff = ['a', undefined]
```

To get back to your function, the correct type would be:

```js
export function shallowDifferences(
  a: string[],
  b: string[]
): (string | undefined)[] | undefined {
  if (a.length !== b.length) return undefined;

  let diff = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === b[i]) {
      diff[i] = a[i];
    } else {
      diff[i] = undefined;
    }
  }

  return diff;
}
```